# A finite $p$-group has a supersolvable series.

Tags: group-theory, p-groups, solvable-groups

I'm being asked to show: Show a finite $p$-group $G$ has a supersolvable series, i.e. a normal series

$$G=G_0\ge G_1\ge\cdots\ge G_m=1$$

such that each factor group is cyclic and each $G_i$ is normal in $G$.

Here are some facts about $p$-groups I know which may or may not help:

(1) $G$ has order $p^n$ for some $n$

(2) $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for each $0\le k\le n$

(3) Given any proper subgroup of order $p^k$ it is contained within some subgroup of order $p^{k+1}$.

I'm not seeing how to put these facts together to show $G$ has a supersolvable series, or if I need anything else. I'd also prefer a push in the right direction, rather than just being given the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A finite $p$-group has a non-trivial center, and any finite abelian group whose order is divisible by $p$ has an element of order $p$. Let $H$ be the cyclic group generated by $p$.  Then $G/H$ is a finite $p$ group, so argue inductively.

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: You're quite welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think (2) also gives it to you ... you have a normal subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$, call it $G_1$.  Then $|G / G_1| = p$, making it cyclic, and thus abelian.  But $G_1$ is also a $p$-group, so it has a normal subgroup of order $p^{n-2}$; call that $G_2$, and induct down to $1$.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late comment but this guarantees that every $G_i$ will be normal in $G$?